# Difference Between "in" Operator and Simple Value Pass c#

Tags: c#

According to c# 7.2

> The "in" operator Passes a variable in to a method by reference. Cannot be set inside the method.

and we can write method like this

```
 public static int Add(in int number1, in int number2)
 {
   return number1 + number2;
 }
```

and call it using

```
 Add(ref myNo,4);
```

Now my question is that, what is the Big difference between calling that one and this one**(with or without "in" operator)**

```
public static int Add(int number1, in int number2)
 {
   return number1 + number2;
 }
```

and Call like

```
Add(3,4);
```

This code also does the same the

> it could not be set if we want

,so if the only difference between "in" and without "in" is that we cannot set inside method? or not. if no please give me another example.

Comment: Basically you can do `number1 = 3;` in the second one, but the first one would give a compile error.  It's basically a way to ensure you don't assign something to a passed in variable.

Comment: It allows you in a bit of a clunky way to have immutable/readonly parameters to methods and you don't need the ref part in the call. This works `Add(myNo, 4);` when using `in` parameters. Other important difference is you can't use `in` parameters in `async` methods or in methods called by closures. I would read this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2018/01/08/c-7-series-part-8-in-parameters/

Comment: the simplest explanation is the variable used with `in` keyword becomes `readonly` hence it can not be modified in the scope of the function whereas the other can be modified. [reference1](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/01/08/new-keyword-c-7-2/), [reference2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-2)

Comment: Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following clearly explains the purpose :

> passes a variable in to a method by reference. Cannot be set inside the method.

[From Official DOCS:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-2)

> The **in** modifier on parameters, to specify that an argument is passed by reference but not modified by the called method.

The only difference is that the incoming parameters value cannot be set within the method when parameters are having `in` operator while in normal parameters we can set whatever value we want, using `in` we restrict from doing that.

For example:

```
 public static int Add(in int number1, in int number2)
 {
   number1 = 2; // this will give compile time error as we cannot set it.
   return number1 + number2;
 }
```

while in normal case we can set whenever we want though in the example it does not makes sense to set but clearly explains the difference:

```
 public static int Add(int number1,int number2)
 {
   number1 = 2; // this works.
   return number1 + number2;
 }
```

So, we can say that the method parameters become immutable technically.

You can read more details about it [here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/01/08/new-keyword-c-7-2/).

Comment: thankyou very much so I conclude that it only restrict user to set before program run

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI nope, it is there for optimization purposes when passing large readonly structs. It makes no sense to use it with an int. The fact that you can't reassign the variable is just a side effect, not the purpose of the in modifier.

Comment: please the read the blogpost mentioned in the answer which talks about how it improves performance for value types where by normal call they are copied by value on method call.